# Float text on right inside a header when header has text-overflow ellipsis

Tags: javascript, css

I have the following HTML and CSS

```css
div
{
    width: 450px;
    background-color: pink;
}

h1
{
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: yellow;
    
}

button
{
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <h1>LONGTEXTLONGTEXTLONGTEXTLONGTEXTLONGTEXTLONGTEXT
        <button type="button">X</button>
    </h1>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0k49bvo9/

The problem I have is how to make the 'x' button go up on same line with text and float right (like how it looks when text is smaller).

I can't modify the HTML, I only need to achieve this by CSS or, if it's really necessary, by JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than making the button float right, you might want to position it absolutely.

```
button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

For the button positioning to be relative to the parent element `h1`, that one has to be positioned either relative or absolute as well.

So you add

```
h1 {
    position: relative;
}
```

In a last step, you add some padding-right to your h1 to make sure your ellipsis (or text) don't overlap with the button:

```
h1 {
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0k49bvo9/2/

Answer (score 1):

Could you maybe do something like this?

```
div
{
    width: 450px;
    background-color: pink;
}

h1
{
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: yellow;
    position:relative; /* adding this */
}

button
{
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    top:0px;
}
```

Adding the position relative to the H1 means that the button with absolute positioning won't break the boundaries of the h1, meaning it will sit on top of the text